# how to add images to Rails email with full url path

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, actionmailer

I want to add images to an email template but don't want to add them inline but with the full path to their location on the server where the application is hosted.

How can I do this in Rails 3 action mailer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in your controller action

```
def example_action
 UserMailer.notifier(request.protocol, request.host_with_port).deliver
end
```

add below in your user_mailer class

```
def notifier(protocol, host)
    @protocol = protocol
    @host = host
    mail(:from => "xxx@xxx.com", :to => "xxxx@xxx.com", :subject => "Ur nice image path")
end
```

in your notifier.html.erb view.

```
<%= image_tag("#{@protocol}#{@host}/images/image_name.xxx")%>
```

Comment: Thanks Sanankhalid. I send mail in my model, can I still access request.protocol and request.hot_with_port from there?

Comment: you can't use request constant in your model, you have to send this via controller.